# How to pass a IList<MyObject> as parameter for a POST method in Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my project, I have a model class called Project and I have a POST method in my REST service, developed in Web API, that I want to receive a list of Project, but always that I call this method, the IList parameter is null. What I have to do to pass a List as a parameter?

That's my controller:

```
[IdentityBasicAuthentication]
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("project")]
public class ProjectController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("listafavoritos")]
    public IList<PROSPERI_EpmFast.Core.Modelo.POCO.Project> ListaFavoritos([FromBody] List<PROSPERI_EpmFast.Core.Modelo.POCO.Project> projetos)
    {
         //execute the actions
    }
}
```

and that's my service call:

```
    public virtual async Task<IList<Project>> ListaProjetosFavoritos(IList<Project> projetosFavoritos)
    {


       var url = "http://myserviceurl/project/listafavoritos";


        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authentication;


        foreach (Project projetoLimpar in projetosFavoritos)
        {
            projetoLimpar.Tasks = null;
            projetoLimpar.Team = null;
            projetoLimpar.Cost = null;
            projetoLimpar.Schedule = null;
        }

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(projetosFavoritos, this._microsoftDateFormatSettings);
        var contentEnvio = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, contentEnvio);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Project>>(content, this._microsoftDateFormatSettings);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the parameter to an array

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("listafavoritos")]
public IList<Project> ListaFavoritos([FromBody]Project[] projetos) { ... }
```

and also convert data to an array when you are sending it

```
//....

var payload = projetosFavoritos.ToArray();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, this._microsoftDateFormatSettings);
var contentEnvio = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

_client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
var response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, contentEnvio);

//....
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.